# after making bar chart inside SVG using D3 , it is not fitting the entire SVG

Tags: javascript, css, angular, d3.js, svg

am plotting in svg the tag  and inside  adding multiple  that fits specific (x,y) from data ( using d3.js lib )
that svg is on slider , ( which is okay when i inspect the svg element , it is fitting )
but the problem is the element  is not fitting , althought i can see width and height : 100% when inspecting .
proof

[image]

my code for this is :

```
private createSvg(): void {
    if (this.svg) {
        return;
    }
    this.svg = d3.select("figure#histogram")
        .classed("svg-container", true)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", '100%')
        .attr("height", '100%')
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400")
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
        .append("g")
        .attr("width", '100%')
        .attr("height", '100%')
}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution :
you should play with this line to adjust your graph :

```
attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400")
```

And also be careful about the range that you give for xAxis , it should contain approriate value !